# How to pass parameters from several sub functions to a major one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, variables

I need your help on how to figure out the following:

With the following functions called AddSub# I want to pass to the main add function (AddAll) the variables called string#

```
function AddSub1()
{       string11 = '11';
        string12= '12';
        string13= '13';
        AddAll(string11, string12, string13);
}

function AddSub2()
{       string21 = '21';
        string22= '22';
        string23= '23';
        AddAll(string21, string22, string23);
}
```

But if I do:

```
function AddAll(string11, string12, string13, string21, string22, string23){
    document.write(string11);
    document.write(string12);
    document.write(string13);
    document.write(string21);
    document.write(string22);
    document.write(string23);
}
```

And I call function AddSub1 I get: 11 12 13 undefined undefined undefined

Then, if I call AddSub2 I get: 21 22 23 undefined undefined undefined

How can I pass the variables to the AddAll function properly so I can get 11 12 13 21 22 23?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use global variables:

```
var string11,string12,string13,string21,string22,string23;

function AddSub1()
{       
    string11= '11';
    string12= '12';
    string13= '13';
}

function AddSub2()
{   
    string21= '21';
    string22= '22';
    string23= '23';
}

function AddAll(){
    document.write(string11);
    document.write(string12);
    document.write(string13);
    document.write(string21);
    document.write(string22);
    document.write(string23);
}
```

and then you call:

```
AddSub1();
AddSub2();
AddAll();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now I understand the importance of global variables!

Comment: This is a dirty solution and I do not understand how you can mark it as correct. 

Global variables should be used as less as possible. Of course you get `undefined` as response of `AddSub#` because inside that function you call `AddAll` giving less parameters than expected.

Other solutions that have been given seems more acceptable.

Or, at least, you should explain us why you need those nested funcs.

Comment: What's my mistake if they understood the question wrong? Of course getting the arguments before printing is the best solution for a "argument echoer" function, but this is not what he asked for. The question itself is questionable, but my answer is to that question. And does exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

You should use arguments, an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

```
function AddAll(){
    var args = arguments; // arguments will give you an array 
                          // of all passed arguments to this function

    // here I keep just a reference in args, 
    // you can also use argumetns itself directly                              

    // To retrieve those arguements use this

    document.write(args[0]);
    document.write(args[1]); // ...etc

    // You can also make a loop over arguments

    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      document.write(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

Read more about [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

**NOTE:**

- Don't use global variable unnecessarily
- Not need to pass arguments to `AddAll()` as `Array`, just `comma(,)` separated

Comment: One downside to this approach is that it isn't obvious that this function expects any arguments or what those arguments are.

Although if your function is variadic then there isn't much choice

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function so that it takes an array of strings.

```
function AddAll(strings) {
    for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        document.write(strings[i]);
    }
}

AddAll(["hello", "world"]);
```

or to use code from your example:

```
function AddSub2() {       
    string21 = '21';
    string22= '22';
    string23= '23';
    AddAll([string21, string22, string23]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a modified version of the answer by @thecodeparadox

```
function AddAll(){
var args = arguments; // arguments will give you an array 

for(var i=0,j=args.length;i<j;i++)
document.write(args[i]);

}
```

that way it does not matter how many strings you pass to the function they will all get written.

from your question it seems that this function will have multiple iterations.